# Prevent a sql trigger from rolling back original transaction on error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In Sql Server 2008 I've been asked to write triggers to do various types of logging in an application I've built.  The problem is my SQL is rusty and sometimes some of the things I put in the triggers to do logging will unexpectedly error out.  I intend to eventually work out all the errors but in the meantime my trigger code is breaking my application because if the trigger unexpectedly fails it rolls back the update or insert that triggered it breaking pieces of the application.  I attempted to put a try catch block around the trigger code but it appears that doesn't do what I'm accustomed to it doing in other languages and it will rollback the original transaction even with that.

Does anybody know how/if you can write a trigger that when it errors it just dies gracefully and lets the transaction that triggered it complete?

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722967/how-to-ignoring-errors-in-trigger-and-perform-respective-operation-in-ms-sql-ser/17724709#17724709 I think it is easier and better to fix your triggers so it does not error.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2163041/1114171](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2163041/1114171)

Comment: It's usually best to queue the work from the trigger, and then pick up the queued work in its own transaction and proceed from there (via service broker, sql agent job, etc).  But that advice only works if you can get past the basics.

Answer (score 4):

You can enclose your trigger body code into a [try-catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg
ON tt
AFTER DELETE
AS
    set xact_abort off; 
    BEGIN TRY
         sql_statements
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
          dies gracefully
    END CATCH;
```

Remember to set [xact_abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to off to avoid automatically rolling back current transaction.

[sql fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/add76/1/0)